# Python: Error printing dictionary with .item()

Tags: python, list, dictionary, printing

I'm starting with dictionaries and while trying to print a dictionary with `.items()`, I got this:

```
dict_items object at 0x0000000000000293B182
```

Here is the code I used:

```
vital_info = {"first_name": "Elvis", "last_name": "Teck", "age": 69, "city": "Quilimari"}
print(vital_info.items())
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem.... but you can always do `print(list(vital_info.items()))` to force output to be a list.

Comment: What is your Python version?

Comment: What version of Python are you using?  Are you using a variant like Anaconda or Jython?

Comment: you need to `list(vital_info.items())` or `tuple(vital_info.items())`,otherwise you only see it is a object

Comment: @kcorlidy his syntax is fine , it should output a all of the items

Comment: Do me a favor, `import sys` and then what does `print(sys.version_info)` and `print(sys.implementation)` give you?

Comment: @JohnGordon Anaconda isn't really another implementation, it is a *distribution* of the normal CPython interpreter/runtime that comes with the `conda` package-manager/virtual-environment system and a bunch of additional libraries related to the py-data stack (numpy, pandas, matplotlib etc)

Comment: I am currently using Python 3.0

Comment: My output for `print(sys.version_info)` is: (3, 0, 1, "final", 0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my error to be solved when reinstalling the path for Python, which had 3.7 installed, while my interpreter used 3.0. The problem was not of the writting itself, but of the system's path.

Answer (score 0):

I asume you are using `python 3.x` (because of the `print()` function you use).

The [`dict.items()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=dict#dict.items) method returns a view, not a list directly in this version of `python`.

To get a list you need to iterate over the view, maybe converting it to a list (using `list()`) or tuple (using `tuple()`). Here is an example:

```
print(list(vital_info.items()))
```